# Extract html <div> tags using NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I want to extract all the div tags from my string using regex , But the problem is I am getting only one match that starts from first `<div>` and ends at last `</div>` ignoring the intermediate `</div>` tags.

Is there a way to create a recursive regex to handle divs inside divs?

```
NSString *nhtml = @"<p>&nbsp;addsfsdf</p>\n <p>asdfasdf</p>\n <div> <button>1</button> \n<h2>ALL tags</h2></div><p></p><p>&nbsp;addsfsdf</p><p>asdfasdf</p><div> \n <button>2</button><h2>New Tag</h2></div><p></p>";
NSError *error = nil;
_recordingTags = [NSMutableArray new];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/^<div>(.|\\s)*</div>$/"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:nhtml options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

    NSString *text = [nhtml substringWithRange:match.range];
    Tag *tag = [Tag new];
    [tag setFromHTML:text];
    [_recordingTags addObject:tag];
}];
```

Comment: Have you checked [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)?

Comment: Try this regex: `<div>(.*?)</div>`

Comment: @JasperPol: It is *almost* a correct regex, but it will also catch `<div> <div><button>1</button></div>`, for example. And it will fail if you have the div tag spanned across multiple lines, or when you have `<div id="res">`. That is why most people will say it is not efficient to use a regex to parse HTML. Although it is possible to some point. And I'd even say it is not that forbidden here as well, but it also depends on how large HTML input you have. If it is a really large input, forget about regex.

Comment: Do you still and really need a regex solution? If not, please remove the question.

Comment: It will be happy to see , if there any solution. one reason why I consider regex because my html isn't very large .

Comment: @IrfanGul I've updated the question with a line about recursive regexs since that need came out later in the comments.

Comment: NSRegularExpression coun't use Balancing group.So you can't checked